# "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySql hosts" when connecting via C#

Tags: c#, mysql

The title pretty much says it all. When I attempt to connect to my SqlServer on my Namecheap hosted web server it throws the "`Unable to connect to any of the specified MySql hosts`" error message.

Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Threading;

namespace Voting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public MySqlConnection connection;
        public string connectionString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread connectThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DatabaseConnect));

            connectThread.Start();
        }

        private void DatabaseConnect()
        {
            Connect.Text = "Loading";

            connectionString = "Server = mywebsiteishere; Port = 3306; Database = thisdatabase; Uid = mypassword; Password = myusername;";

            try
            {
                connection = new MySqlConnection();

                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                connection.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Success!");
            }

            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            Connect.Text = "Connect";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to note that in the `connectionString` variable, the Server, Database, UID and Password are all in working order.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you put a break point on `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` or wherever you are getting that message. View the other properties of the exception. Perhaps they will give you a hint as to how to fix the issue.

Comment: Hey! Just did that, and got an error code of -2147467259. Huh.

Comment: Have you installed the connector driver for MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html?

Comment: Yep. I already have that installed.

Comment: Can you try to simply call the method DatabaseConnect() and not open a new thread for it? And please change MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException to Exception and give the full error message. Thanks.

Comment: Hey! This program is to be used inside of a GUI, so the thread keeps the window from freezing up. I also changed the 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' to 'Exception' and it returned the same error message. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't help but notice you had `Uid = mypassword; Password = myusername;`. You didn't actually switch around the `Uid` and `Password` did you?

Comment: Ha! Nah, that's all fine in the code. I dunno why I mixed em up while editing the question.